# Adding content in Gutenberg editor

Tags: editor, post-editor, block-editor

I updated my site to the latest version of Wordpress.  I started using the new editor but have a question.

Is there a way to add a block of content that holds all the header tags and paragraph tags?  As far as I can tell I have to create a new "block" for each element, which seems weird.

I tried the HTML block but it does have any options to add elements.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.

There is a feature called "nested blocks" that will let a developer create a block that contains other blocks. This is useful for specific template-type approaches.

But, if you're asking just as a general content author if you can easily put your blocks all together, no, you cannot. They are designed to be separate. It does take some getting used to in your writing workflow. If you run into major issues with it, such as tabbing between items or something like that, the best thing to do is raise a GitHub issue/feature request.

Comment: I was asking more as a general content author but perhaps I can set something up with nested blocks.  Is this what your referring to - https://raquelmsmith.com/blog/how-to-create-nested-blocks-for-gutenberg I am having a hard time find much documentation on it

Comment: Yes - it's very complex, and the documentation out there is lacking. The WP Core team is working on updating all the documentation to make it easier to follow, but even if you're comfortable coding in PHP it's kind of a whole new world coding for the new editor, because most of it is JavaScript that needs to be compiled.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't.  I'm not a fan either...there was no reason to remove this ability, imho.  You could install the classic editor though to get it back though, that's what I do.  It's available as a plugin.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Do you think at some point you will have to switch to Gutenberg though?  I thought I read somewhere about support for the classic editor ending after a couple years.

Comment: maybe, but by that time, someone will have fixed this (if enough people complain) or a third party will have a permanent alternate solution.